# MSBuild batching multiple inputs into each output

Tags: msbuild

Is it possible to dependency-check multiple inputs for each output when using MSBuild batching?

I thought I'd found a solution to this by constructing my inputs list in the metadata of the output file, as follows:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Foo Include="output1">
    <Inputs>input1a;input1b</Inputs>
  </Foo>
  <Foo Include="output2">
    <Inputs>input2a;input2b</Inputs>
  </Foo>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="_CompileFoo" Outputs="@(Foo)" Inputs="%(Foo.Inputs)">
    <FooCompiler Src="%(Foo.Inputs)" Out="@(Foo)" />
</Target>
```

However, MSBuild complains that the file "input1a;input1b" does not exist. It seems that the string->items conversion takes place before the expression evaluation.

Is there any solution to this other than writing my own dependency checking?

Comment: Try taking out the `Outputs` and `Inputs` Target attributes.

Comment: Then it won't do dependency checking, it will always run FooCompiler for every item.

Comment: Where is it doing dependency checking?

Comment: That's what the Inputs and Outputs are for. For each item in the batch, MSBuild can skip the item if the output exists and is newer than the input.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Checking multiple dependencies works if the item group is set up the other way round with the compilation result as metadata.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Foo Include="input1a">
    <Result>output1</Result>
  </Foo>
  <Foo Include="input1b">
    <Result>output1</Result>
  </Foo>
  <Foo Include="input2a">
    <Result>output2</Result>
  </Foo>
  <Foo Include="input2b">
    <Result>output2</Result>
  </Foo>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="_CompileFoo" Inputs="@(Foo)" Outputs="%(Result)">
  <FooCompiler Overwrite="true" Src="@(Foo)" Out="%(Foo.Result)"/>
</Target>
```

And instead of manually converting the `Foo` item group, you can transform this in a prerequisite target building a new item group `_Foo` as follows.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Foo Include="output1">
    <Inputs>input1a;input1b</Inputs>
  </Foo>
  <Foo Include="output2">
    <Inputs>input2a;input2b</Inputs>
  </Foo>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="_PrepareItemsForCompileFoo">
  <ItemGroup>
    <_Foo Include="%(Foo.Inputs)">
      <Result>%(Foo.Identity)</Result>
    </_Foo>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="_CompileFoo" DependsOnTargets="_PrepareItemsForCompileFoo" Inputs="@(_Foo)" Outputs="%(Result)">
  <FooCompiler Overwrite="true" Src="@(_Foo)" Out="%(_Foo.Result)"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! The items in my example were actually created by aggregating other items using a C# task. Thanks to your second example, I was able to eliminate it.